# WSL2 Ubuntu Python 3.10.4 interpreter sees quotation mark as a syntax error

Tags: python, shell, syntax, wsl-2

```
> python record_data.py --browser chrome --num_runs 1 --sites_list google.com --trace_length 5
  File "record_data.py", line 125
    response = input(f"{prompt} [y/N] ")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This syntax error does not rise in powershell.

Any ideas why should this happen?

This is the code around it:

```
if opts.enable_timer_countermeasure and opts.attacker_type != "javascript":
    print("If enable_timer_countermeasure is true, attacker_type must be set to javascript.")
    sys.exit(1)

def confirm(prompt):
    response = input(f"{prompt} [y/N] ")

    if "y" not in response.lower():
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like what we would see from Bash in a script with DOS/Windows CRLF line-endings, but as far as I'm aware, Python interpreters on both platforms should handle either line-ending.  That said, I wonder if, since you can run it from Windows but not from Linux/WSL, that there's some CRLF corner-case that's coming into play.